# How-to run a node.js docker instance dropping into a shell that is auto-tailing logs

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, package.json

SO...

I am trying to create an elegant docker / node setup for my team on a greenfield prototype project. My team will need to have Node / NPM and Docker CLI installed beforehand, but afterwards I will be using NPM to manage everything and previously had...

```
"scripts": {
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && npm run docker-start",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t docker_foo .",
    "docker-start": "docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm docker_foo",
    "start": "node server.js"
}
```

...and the Dockerfile contains the CMD...

```
# Other stuff...

EXPOSE  8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

...that will eventually start the node server. This works really well for seeing logs and cleaning up containers, but I want to make it better. I would like to instead start the container in the background using the -d option and attach to the container instead with an initial command tailing the logs to simulate the same behavior except that when the user terminates the process, they are still in the container so they can evaluate the container's current state. This led me to have...

```
"scripts": {
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && npm run docker-start && npm run docker-attach",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t docker_foo .",
    "docker-start": "docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name docker_foo docker_foo",
    "docker-attach": "docker exec -it docker_foo /bin/ash",
    "docker-clean": "npm run docker-clean-containers && npm run docker-clean-images",
    "docker-clean-containers": "docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm -f -v",
    "docker-clean-images": "docker images -f 'dangling=true' -q | xargs docker rmi",
    "start": "node server.js"
}
```

...but I am having some trouble finding where the node server logs are stored either on the container or on my local host to enable this desired workflow. Is there some way to re-direct the STD out and err to a location inside the container for historical purposes and a way to expand my attach command above to initially be tailing those logs?

Comment: have you considered using `docker logs docker_foo`?

Comment: True, that would work... especially ```docker logs -f docker_foo``` so you can tail the logs from the host machine, but strangely I am unable to locate the log file. Running the following... ```docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' docker_foo``` yields a path (/var/lib/docker/containers/d6797a784663ff7b8f3626e78ee4db5b6c7f6b2c1521d37a012c45664f8f0d7d/d6797a784663ff7b8f3626e78ee4db5b6c7f6b2c1521d37a012c45664f8f0d7d-json.log) that doesn't exist in my container nor on my local box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is simply starting the node server in the background...

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "build": "docker build -t docker_foo .",
    "clean": "npm run clean:containers && npm run clean:images && npm run clean:volumes",
    "clean:containers": "docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm -f -v",
    "clean:images": "docker images -f 'dangling=true' -q | xargs docker rmi",
    "clean:volumes": "docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs docker volume rm",
    "prerun": "npm run build",        
    "run": "docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name docker_foo -v $(pwd)/app:/usr/src/docker_foo/app -v $(pwd)/test:/usr/src/docker_foo/test docker_foo",
    "start": "nodemon --watch app server.js",
    "logs": "docker logs -f admin_api",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "docker run -p 8080:8080 --name docker_foo -it --rm docker_foo node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
    "prewatch": "npm run run",
    "watch": "docker exec -it docker_foo node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec \"node_modules/.bin/_mocha -w\""
}
```

...so I could run "npm run run" and it would run my docker instance in the background with the service filesystem overlayed with my own hosts' being watched by nodemon for file changes for rapid application development and then I could run "npm run logs" afterwards to tail the logs during development.

Alternatively, I can now run "npm run watch" to have the docker image / container / volume cleaned, re-built and ran with nodemon watching to restart the server and mocha watching the app and test directories to re-run the tests and constantly output the results to the window.